# Find Not Returning Value Even When Present

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a value in a column, then add a row after the last row with data after the found value. The issue I'm encountering is when finding the value using the Find function - when testing I receive

> Runtime Error 91: Object Variable of With block variable not set

During my troubleshooting I found that this error gets thrown when trying to access an attribute of the result of a Find that did not find a match. However, I know there is a match within the given range.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FirstRow As Range
    
    'issue here
    FirstRow = Range("B:B").Find("SearchTerm")
    
    ' Find last row with data
    With Range(FirstRow.Address).CurrentRegion
        LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
    End With
    
    'add row
    Rows(LastRow & ":" & LastRow).Insert Shift:=x1Down
End Sub
```

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: `Set FirstRow=`  and also check that it does not return Nothing.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `With` block to find the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have your syntax correct for setting an object variable. You need to use `Set`.

```
FirstRow = Range("B:B").Find("SearchTerm")
```

should be:

```
Set FirstRow = Range("B:B").Find("SearchTerm")
```